# Where does the sass "font-url" method get defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, bourbon

[bourbon](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon) uses `font-url` [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/css3/_font-face.scss).

Rails has the method `font_url` which I'm fairly certain is what is being invoked. However, I can't find where the connection between these two things is made. I have explored the codebases of bourbon, sass, sass-rais, and rails.

Where is `font-url` defined, and/or the connection between it and rails's `font_url` made?

**update**

Clarification: my ultimate goal is to define my own helpers in rubyland which are siblings to font_url.

Answer (score 9):

***font-url is a part of rails asset pipeline just like image-url***. If you look at [`rail guides`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass) it clearly says

> When using the asset pipeline, paths to assets must be re-written and sass-rails provides -url and -path helpers (hyphenated in Sass, underscored in Ruby) for the following asset classes: image, font, video, audio, JavaScript and stylesheet.

So if you are using **`font-url("some_font")` it will look for some_font in app/assets/font directory**

**Update:**

As it is mentioned in docs that if you are using sass *then your can use your assets with hypenated urls(image-url) but if you are using a ruby file then [`those helpers would be underscored`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html)* (image_url) probably because ***Ruby doesn't like you having methods or variables with hyphens*** in the name *syntactically*, but semantically, there's nothing wrong with it

Comment: great, getting closer. but can you point out where in the rails code the translation from hyphen to underscore takes place?

Comment: (also, the docs seem to indicate that sass-rails provides this, but your answer seems to indicate that rails provides this)

Comment: @JohnBachir yeah sass-rails provides it. I only said that it's a part of a rails asset pipeline. If you are using sass then you can use hypenated url but if you want to use your assets in a ruby file then those helpers are with underscore. I think both of these helpers are exclusive to each others as they are defined separately

Comment: I could not find where the hyphen version is defined, and this is what I am asking in my question. My goal is to define my own helper. I'll update the question to reflect that.

Comment: @JohnBachir Ahh couldn't find the source of image-url btw if you want to define helpers which are siblings to font_url then why are you looking for a source of font-url? I mean you could just define a method and then replicate what's inside font_url helper. If you want your method name to have hypen then you can checkout this https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/72154#101895

Comment: Making hyphen interchangeable with underscore is a feature of Sass.  However, depending on how the function is defined, this might not always work.

Comment: How do I define a method in ruby that a sibling to font-url which I can use in SASS?

Comment: Just use Compass?  http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/urls/#font-url