# asset sass helpers: difference between image_url and image-url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, assets

I've noticed that both helpers image_url and image-url work in my scss files, but they aren't generating the same path. What is the difference between these two functions?

Although I checked my environment configuration for the asset.prefix path, they generate different prefix when rendering assets.

Comment: this [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25457893/where-does-the-sass-font-url-method-get-defined) can answers you

Answer (score 0):

This is the main difference

For image url which is called `asset_url` or `url_to_asset` method with `type image` so it will go to image directory

```
   url_to_asset(source, {type: :image}.merge!(options))
```

For assets url you can call for js or any other assets(video,audio,stylesheet..)

```
 path_to_asset(source, options.merge(:protocol => :request))
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d4b0e5f59f599a386d43a7f4d005430e87ae7ec4/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb#L316

Answer (score 0):

It is the *same helper*.  From the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass)

> When using the asset pipeline, paths to assets must be re-written and sass-rails provides -url and -path helpers (**hyphenated in Sass**, **underscored in Ruby**) for the following asset classes: image, font, video, audio, JavaScript and stylesheet.

`-url` is used for sass, `_url` is used for Ruby.

It is convention in css and sass to use hypen-seperated words for functions; whereas in Ruby, it is convention to use [snakecase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case).

Both functions should have the *same behaviour* and hence generate the paths that point to the *same asset directory*. If they do not, then you are probably experiencing a bug similar to: [sass-rails asset pipeline: generating image paths incorrectly; `url(/images/blah.png)` instead of `url(/assets/blah.png)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11040366/3649209)